# After Upgrade to Django 2.1 500 error messages are not sent anymore

Tags: python, django

Since I upgraded my site to Django 2.1 the error emails with the 500 information are not sent anymore.

I did not change the settings in anyway.

They look like this (excerpt from diffsettings)

```
SERVER_EMAIL = 'bla@example.com'
### LOGGING = {}
### LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
ADMINS = [('Admin', 'admin@example.com')]
### DEBUG = False
```

As you can see i have the default logging config, and debug is set to false.
I also tested my email settings and when i manually send an email(with the server email address as sender and the admin email address as receiver everything works fine. 
I did not fin anything that this is a known bug in Django 2.1

Answer (score 1):

I send messages to Google Chat based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/chasetb/c4c29f95ff53fb5d9267293b56c35eea#file-b-settings-py).  Since upgrading to Django 2.1, this stopped working even though the config stayed the same (much like your situation). While I'm not entirely sure what is happening, I found that if I changed my server's DEBUG to True and changed the filter on my 'chat_admins' logging handler to 'require_debug_true' it would work again. Of course this is not ideal as it's in Production, where DEBUG is 'False', that I need this to work.

I ended up rewriting my LOGGING variable in settings.py, trying to get a minimal configuration and following the documenation for [Django Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging). and it is now working in Production with DEBUG to 'True'.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[{server_time}] {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
    },
     'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'django.server': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'django.server',
        },
        'chat_admins': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'myapp.chat_logger.ChatExceptionHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'chat_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['django.server'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

There are only two main differences between the original settings and my re-write: 1) the 'mail_admins' handler is gone and 2) 'propagate' in the django logger is now set to 'True'. I tried manually applying those settings to the prior config as well but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Not related to OP's question, but rather for @chase.tb -- I upgrade to Django 2.1 from 1.11 without realizing the ADMINS settings changed from a tuple of tuples to list of tuples. After fix that, email works again.

Comment: This particular Django project was started w/ v2.0 where the ADMINS setting was already treated as a list of tuples.